# How to forward to Lightswitch html client from domain root deployed on Azure Websites

Tags: azure, visual-studio-lightswitch, azure-web-app-service, domain-masking

I have successfully deployed a Lightswitch HTML application to Azure Websites.  I have also forwarded my personal domain to mask the azurewebsite.net address.  I am now able to access the site by typing mydomain.com/htmlclient and everything works fine.  If I type in just the my domain.com, however,  I get the you do not have permission error.

This is close but ultimately I would like to be able to enter just the domain and have it automatically forward to the htmlclient folder.  I know it is possible but I'm not sure if I can get there with settings in azure or my domain host or if I have to drop a page in the root (it appears that the default and login.aspx pages for forms authentication are already in the root).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the Visual Studio 2013 version we've found this is simply a case of adding an additional entry to the LightSwitch server project's web.config file.

This additional entry needs to reference the default.aspx file (which should already be part of the server project) and should be introduced into the defaultDocument section of the web.config.  In the following example, this new line appears immediately after the standard default.htm line: -

```
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear />
    <add value="default.htm" />
    <add value="default.aspx" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```